# how to fix over released objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, autorelease, nszombie

NSZombie detected that one of the objected is over released in my app and that is causing the app to crash every time when a button is pressed. However, after inspecting the source code of where the over release happens, I couldn't see any obvious code that that may have caused the release. Can xcode release objects automatically without any actual code?

Below are the places reported by the Instrument that has a release event:

```
-(void) takePicture:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
    CDVCameraPicker* cameraPicker = [[CDVCameraPicker alloc] init];
    self.pickerController = cameraPicker;
    CameraOverlayViewController* overlay = [[CameraOverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraOverlayViewController" bundle:nil];
    cameraPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView = overlay.view;

    [self.viewController presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you explicitly releasing anything in your code somewhere else?

Comment: Are you using ARC or MRC?

Comment: @mostruash No, and these are the only places that reported back from NSZombie with a release event. In fact I know it is the CameraOverlayViewController that is causing the problem, but I can't find where is it over released.

Comment: @rmaddy ARC, but the event type is not autorelease tho.

Comment: You can profile it using the Zombies instrument to figure this out. It will show you the entire retain/release history of the object, allowing you to figure out which retains/releases are unbalanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CameraOverlayViewController is released.

Try the below code

```
CameraOverlayViewController* overlay;
    -(void) takePicture:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
    CDVCameraPicker* cameraPicker = [[CDVCameraPicker alloc] init];
    self.pickerController = cameraPicker;
    overlay = [[CameraOverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraOverlayViewController" bundle:nil];
    cameraPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView = overlay.view;

    [self.viewController presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You should clarify your change. It appears you mean that an ivar should be used for the overlay view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a CameraOverlayViewController and keeping a reference to it's view, but the  CameraOverlayViewController itself is going out of scope when the takePicture: method ends. A view doesn't retain it's view controller. You need to either keep a reference to the CameraOverlayViewController, or if you're only interested in the view object itself, just create a view from the xib file and set the cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView to that view.

EDIT:

For example, in your header file you could make a property:

```
@property (strong) CameraOverlayViewController *overlay;
```

and in your method:

```
-(void) takePicture:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
    CDVCameraPicker* cameraPicker = [[CDVCameraPicker alloc] init];
    self.pickerController = cameraPicker;

    self.overlay = [[CameraOverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraOverlayViewController" bundle:nil];
    cameraPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay.view;

    [self.viewController presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Once you're done with the camera, you'll want to let go of the reference. So for example:

```
-(void) cameraPickerFinished {
   self.overlay = nil;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by keep a reference to the CameraOverlayViewController? Could you put down some code?

Comment: But after doing this I will get the below error message when that button is pressed:
\[CameraOverlayViewController select:forEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance\
Does this mean that the select method is trying to use a alrdy released controller?